# Vaadin application, jump to page top

Tags: java, vaadin

I have a vaadin application that has an outer panel, and upload this lot, interior panels. This case the entire bottom of the page (the bottom panel) jumps. How I know this time will automatically jump to the top?

The "`window.getApplication().getMainWindow.setScrolleft(x)`" does not work, because they do not want a scrolling panebut also you want the browser to jump to the top.

Thanks G

---

I tried vaadin 6.7(still in beta), but still it produces the error.

Answer (score 1):

this is most probably due to a bug in vaadin that has been fixed in the 6.7 branch.

HTH